# State managment for too large angular application

Tags: angular, ngrx, nrwl-nx

Recently I came across a situation In our application, I searched for the solution but nowhere found a proper answer, As you know we have more than 600+ modules in our application. As the user navigates to new pages the browser may fill up with new states and it's data. So we are planning to clear all other feature states as entering a new module. And only keeping the root state alive throughout the application. I would like to know whether my approach is right or not? if it is fine then what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why having a huge state would be an issue at all.

It would be an issue if you where writing a lot to it because as it's immutable you'd need to update all the references higher up in the chain. But if you touch another part of the state only when you're on a different module, then when the store is updated, the part that you didn't modify will be reused (by reference) which is really cheap.

One thing you could do on the other hand, is to watch from an effect when you leave the current module and trigger a cleanup (reset to default state?) for the current reducer.

About all the selectors, if you use `createSelector` it's using memoization and so as the reference will not change for "unused" part of the store, it'll return the previous value directly.

Why do you feel that need of cleaning up your state? I'm curious. If it's because of a perf issue I'd say that it's probably unrelated to that exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, Here my concern that consider a list of cars where user able to set maximum item can be seen in a page to 1000 and after that he goes to another few lists like bikes, truck ..etc in each page he set maximum visible items to 1000 if he navigates to all these pages with few hours the browser will fill up with these data . This kind of features required in the business application so we have no option other than cleaning state as he moves to another module.